# DevExpress ASPxDropDownEdit with scrollable DropDownWindowTemplate

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have made use of the DevExpress ASPxDropDownEdit and DropDownWindowTemplate.
I have copied the example from the DevExpress demo site to setup my page - [link to demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxEditorsDemos/ASPxDropDownEdit/DropDownEdit.aspx)

Now the problem I'm having is when the Drop Down gets too many values, it extended outside of the page and i cannot select values lower down in the drop down box.
Am I able to place a scroll bar in the DropDownWindowTemplate so I can fix the height?

I have tried setting the Height of the Grid within my DropDownWindowTemplate as well as setting the DropDownWindowHeight on the ASPxDropDownEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the Div element into the DropDownWindowTemplate and set its style.height property to some value.  If you set the div's style.overflow attribute to Auto, this Div element will show scrollbars when it is necessary.  Finally, you will have to include the required content to this DIV.